# td background colouring applied to complete column rather to a single cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've below html.

```
 <table border="1" class="myTable">
               <tr>
                  <th class="cname">Component</th>
                  <th class="pname">Properties</th>
                     <th class="sname">lqwasb02</th>
               </tr>
                     <tr>
                     <td class="cname">EMWBISConfig</td>
                     <td class="pname">reEvaluationTimer</td>
                        <td class="pvalue">every 1 hour without catch up</td>
                     </tr>                     
                     <tr>
                     <td class="cname">CalculateCategoryMediaInfoService</td>
                     <td class="pname">scheduled</td>
                        <td class="pvalue">yes</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                     <td class="cname">EMWBISScheduler</td>
                     <td class="pname">scheduled</td>
                        <td class="pvalue">no</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                     <td class="cname">CatalogTools</td>
                     <td class="pname">loggingDebug</td>
                        <td class="pvalue">false</td>
                     </tr>
             </table>
```

Below is the jquery I've written.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           var list = ['every 1 hour without catch up','yes','yes','false'];
           $.each(list,function(index,value){
              //alert(index+' : '+value);
           });

           var idx;var list2 = new Array();

           // Find index of cell with 'lqwasb02'
           $('.myTable th').each(function(index) {
             if ($(this).text() === 'lqwasb02') idx = index;
           });

          // Loop through each cell with the same index
            $('.myTable tr').each(function() {
               if($(this).find('td:eq('+idx+')').text() !=""){
                  list2.push($(this).find('td:eq('+idx+')').text());
               }
           }); var idx2 = [];
              for(var x=0;x<list2.length;x++){
                  if(list[x]===list2[x]){
                      //console.log(list[x]);
                  }else{
                      console.log('mismatched : '+list[x]);
                      $('.myTable tr').each(function() {
                        $(this).find('td:eq('+x+')').css("background-color", "red");
                      });
                      idx2.push(x);
                  }
              }
});
```

I'm trying to compare values in `list` with values in `lqwasb02` column and if it finds the difference, it should highlight the background of `td` cell in red colour.

Current issue with jquery code, it is highlighting the complete column.

Can someone please help me where I'm getting wrong? If possible, please pass on the recommended solutions.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your .find you are returning multiple elements that it's selector matches. So as opposed to storing the text value for your td elements in the second array, just store the actual td element, compare it's text, and then you can assign the background color directly to the element as opposed to finding it again via it's index:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var list = ['every 1 hour without catch up','yes','yes','false'];
    $.each(list,function(index,value){
       //alert(index+' : '+value);
    });
    var idx;var list2 = new Array();
    // Find index of cell with 'lqwasb02'
    $('.myTable th').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).text() === 'lqwasb02') idx = index;
    });
    // Loop through each cell with the same index
    $('.myTable tr').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('td:eq('+idx+')').text() !=""){
            list2.push($(this).find('td:eq('+idx+')')); // <-- Store the object here, not it's text value.
        }
    }); 
  
    var idx2 = [];
    for(var x=0; x < list2.length; x++){
        if(list[x]===list2[x].text()) { // <-- compare list[x] to the text value of list2[x]
            //console.log(list[x]);
        } else {
            list2[x].css("background-color", "red"); // <-- no find or selector needed, just apply it to the object you stored earlier.
        };
    idx2.push(x);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th class="cname">Component</th>
        <th class="pname">Properties</th>
        <th class="sname">lqwasb02</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cname">EMWBISConfig</td>
        <td class="pname">reEvaluationTimer</td>
        <td class="pvalue">every 1 hour without catch up</td>
    </tr>                     
    <tr>
        <td class="cname">CalculateCategoryMediaInfoService</td>
        <td class="pname">scheduled</td>
        <td class="pvalue">yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cname">EMWBISScheduler</td>
        <td class="pname">scheduled</td>
        <td class="pvalue">no</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cname">CatalogTools</td>
        <td class="pname">loggingDebug</td>
        <td class="pvalue">false</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.myTable tr').each(function() {
     $(this).find('td:eq('+x+')').css("background-color", "red");
});
```

this piece of code assign a background colour to each cell of index 'x' for each rows (each cells of index x of each table rows represent a column).

You have to select only the rows which contains the cells you want to colour.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i would have approached solving this issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var list = ['every 1 hour without catch up','yes','yes','false'];
  var colIndex = findColIndex('lqwasb02');

  // Loop over table rows
  $('tr').each(function(){
   // Look up cell with specific index
   var $cell = $(this).find('td').eq(colIndex);
   // Check if the text of the cell is not present in the list and do smth
   if ($.inArray($cell.text(), list) === -1) {
     $cell.css('background', 'red')
   }
  });
});

// helper function to find the index of column by text in the header
function findColIndex (headerText) {
  var $col = $('.myTable th:contains(' + headerText + ')');
  return $('.myTable th').index($col);
}
```

https://jsbin.com/fafegi/1/edit?js,output